# $T$ is isomorphism implies $T^*$ is isomorphism, spaces not necessarily complete

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that if $T:X\to Y$ is isomorphism between normed spaces, then so is $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$, defined by 
$$T^*(y^*)=y^*(T).$$

Suppose $a\neq b$ in $Y^*$ but $T^*(a)=T^*(b)$. Then
$$0=T^*a-T^*b=T^*(a-b)=(a-b)T$$

So $(a-b)T$ is the zero operator from $X\to Y$. Since $T\neq 0$, $a-b
=0\Rightarrow a=b$, a contradiction.
Not sure what to do for surjectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is an isomorphism implies that $T$ has an inverse $T^{-1}$, $TT^{-1}=Id$ and $T^{-1}T=Id$. This implies that $(TT^{-1})^*=(T^{-1})^*T^*=Id$
and $(T^{-1}T)^*=T^*(T^{-1})^*=Id$.

Comment: Can I also ask how the norm $T^*$ is defined?

Comment: the norm of $T^*$.